# Creating a USER using the imp command

Tags: oracle, import, export, users

I was told I can use `exp` to export a certain USER, then DROP the user and with the `imp` command I can recreate that USER with all of its tables.

1. Is it true?
2. How do I do it?

I already have an ADMIN user with just about all privileges (there are 204 of them if it matters).

I tried various options of exporting the USER with the ADMIN account or with the USER's account, but no matter what I do the `imp` command fails if I try to run it when the USER has been dropped.

Example command:

```
-- From CLI:
exp USERID=MYUSER/PASS@INSTANCE FILE=mydump.dmp FULL=y
-- From SQLPLUS with admin user
DROP USER MYUSER CASCADE;
-- From CLI:
imp ADMIN/PASS@INSTANCE FILE=mydump.dmp FULL=y
-- The above command will put the contents of MYUSER into the ADMIN account ...
imp ADMIN/PASS@INSTANCE FILE=mydump.dmp FROMUSER=MYUSER TOUSER=MYUSER 
-- The above command fails with  the below message:

. importing MYUSER's objects into MYUSER
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1435 encountered
ORA-01435: user does not exist
Import terminated successfully with warnings.
```

Comment: Please also note that `expdp`/`impdp` should be used in general instead of `exp`/`imp` unless you're dealing with ancient versions.

Comment: @Mat - you are correct, the answer in the related question does apply to my question - but it was not clear (to me) from the answer that I MUST create the user before IMP can import into it

Comment: @Mat - thanks, I was told that expdp/impdp cannot work from a client, only from the server. And I need to run it form a client

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. The error tells you the user doesn't exist. If the utility could create it, don't you think it would, or at least you'd have found an option in the docs to tell it to?

Comment: That option is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: And... is there one? If not, what's your problem with people answering that you have to create it yourself?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10184/discussion-between-ronk-and-mat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question - the answer is NO - the `imp` command cannot create the user for me.